# fallo al intentar subir un pdf a un servidor desde android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, retrofit

este es el fallo que me sale:
j

> ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.String com.example.subirarchivos.ResponsePOJO.getRemarks()'
> on a null object reference
> at com.example.subirarchivos.MainActivity$3.onResponse(MainActivity.java:72)

Este es mi codigo:

```
private void uploadDocument() {

        Call<ResponsePOJO> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getAPI().uploadDocument(encodedPDF);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePOJO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponsePOJO> call, Response<ResponsePOJO> response) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getRemarks(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponsePOJO> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

este es el metodo que para subir un pdf

el fallo aparece en el toas del onResponse

Answer (score 0):

Si obtienes este error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.String com.example.subirarchivos.ResponsePOJO.getRemarks()'

Se debe a que la peticiòn no obtuvo ninguna respuesta. Para esta implementaciòn es demasiado importante tener definidos los permisos

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y realizar la peticiòn manual del permiso [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Te sugiero tambièn revisar el tutorial:

[Retrofit, Subir y descargar archivos](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-upload-file-tutorial/)

Comment: gracias me funciono

Comment: Excelente, recuerda marcar @favilamontero la respuesta como solución si esta ayudo a solucionar el problema, revisa [tour], saludos.